# ClassCastException while trying to get the generic type parameter

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I want to get instance of generic using reflection:

```
        this.wrapperInstance = ((Class<WRAPPER>) ((ParameterizedType) (getClass().getGenericSuperclass())).getActualTypeArguments()[1]).newInstance();
```

but I get exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
```

Do not know where is problem, maybe someaone can help me? There is full class code:

```
public class XMLUtils<MODEL extends AbstractModel, WRAPPER extends WraperInterface<MODEL>> {

private WRAPPER wrapperInstance;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public XMLUtils() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    this.wrapperInstance = ((Class<WRAPPER>) ((ParameterizedType) (getClass().getGenericSuperclass())).getActualTypeArguments()[1]).newInstance();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<MODEL> loadDataFromXML(String fileName) {

    try {

        File pajamuFile = new File(
                UserDataLoader.INSTANCE.getCurrentUserFolder() + fileName);
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(wrapperInstance.getClass());
        Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
        WRAPPER wrapper = (WRAPPER) um.unmarshal(pajamuFile);
        return wrapper.getDataList();
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new ArrayList<MODEL>();
    }
}

public void saveDataToXML(List<MODEL> dataList, String fileName) {
    try {

        File pajamuFile = new File(
                UserDataLoader.INSTANCE.getCurrentUserFolder() + fileName);
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(wrapperInstance.getClass());
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        WRAPPER wrapper = wrapperInstance;
        wrapper.setDataList(dataList);
        m.marshal(wrapper, pajamuFile);
    } catch (JAXBException  e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

In google I find most such like situation but with spring, here I am not using spring, so maybe there is any clear solution for that what I want to do.

Comment: @Edgar Have a look at [TypeTools](https://github.com/jhalterman/typetools), which allows you to resolve a generic type without requiring you to pass around a class reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do not know where is problem, maybe someaone can help me

The error message is self explanatory. The following statement returns a `Class` :

```
(getClass().getGenericSuperclass())
```

And you are trying to cast it to a `ParameterizedType`

```
((ParameterizedType) (getClass().getGenericSuperclass()))
```

`Class` and `ParameterizedType` are siblings. A brother is not a sister so trying to cast them into one another would be cruel.

That being said, a quick solution to your problem would be to ask the client code to pass the `Class` type to your `XmlUtils` class.

```
public class XMLUtils<MODEL extends AbstractModel, WRAPPER extends WraperInterface<MODEL>> {

private WRAPPER wrapperInstance;

public XMLUtils(Class<WRAPPER> wrapperInstance) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    this.wrapperInstance = wrapperInstance    
 }
 //more code follows
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for advice. I was trying to do like here, but probbably I misundertand something: http://blog.xebia.com/2009/02/07/acessing-generic-types-at-runtime-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect as result?

To simplify your question one cans say you have the following class:

```
class XMLUtils extends java.lang.Object {
  public XMLUtils() {
      getClass().getGenericSuperclass()// == java.lang.Object
  }
}
```

Now you are trying to cast `java.lang.Object` to `ParameterizedType` but that will only work in case the class is a generic class. Therefore it fails...

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use `TypeVariable` instead of `ParameterizedType`.

Have you checked the type of the object returned from `getClass().getGenericSuperclass()`? i.e.

```
Class<?> c = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();

if (c instanceof ParameterizedType) {
  System.out.println("It is an instanceof ParameterizedType");
}
else if (c instanceof TypeVariable) {
  System.out.println("It is an instanceof TypeVariable");
}
else {
  System.out.println("It is something else");
}
```